# How can somebody have so many talents?

Tags: the-law-of-ueki

Somewhere around episode 7, we learned that the average power user has about **160** talents, and we were even introduced to someone with **215** talents (the diamond head guy).

But as far as I understood, you start out with **10** and lose one whenever you beat an innocent person and gain one when you beat a power user.

There are also only **100** participants. And to get 215 talents you would need to beat 205 people.

So is there another way to gain talents?